# How could I make this EF Core query better?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to fetch from the database this:

- rack
- it's type
- single shelf with all its boxes and their box types
- single shelf above the previous shelf without boxes and with shelf type

Shelves have `VerticalPosition` which is in centimeters from the ground - when I am querying for e.g. second shelf in rack, I need to order them and select shelf on index 1.

I have this ugly EF query now:

```cs
var targetShelf = await _warehouseContext.Shelves
    .Include(s => s.Rack)
        .ThenInclude(r => r.Shelves)
            .ThenInclude(s => s.Type)
    .Include(s => s.Rack)
        .ThenInclude(r => r.Type)
    .Include(s => s.Rack)
        .ThenInclude(r => r.Shelves)
    .Include(s => s.Boxes)
        .ThenInclude(b => b.BoxType)
    .Where(s => s.Rack.Aisle.Room.Number == targetPosition.Room)
    .Where(s => s.Rack.Aisle.Letter == targetPosition.Aisle)
    .Where(s => s.Rack.Position == targetPosition.Rack)
    .OrderBy(s => s.VerticalPosition)
    .Skip(targetPosition.ShelfNumber - 1)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

but this gets all boxes from all shelves and it also shows warning

```
Compiling a query which loads related collections for more than one collection navigation, either via 'Include' or through projection, but no 'QuerySplittingBehavior' has been configured. By default, Entity Framework will use 'QuerySplittingBehavior.SingleQuery', which can potentially result in slow query performance.
```

Also I would like to use `AsNoTracking()`, because I don't need change tracker for these data.

First thing: for `AsNoTracking()` I would need to query `Racks`, because it complains about circular include.

Second thing: I tried conditional include like this:

```cs
.Include(r => r.Shelves)
    .ThenInclude(s => s.Boxes.Where(b => b.ShelfId == b.Shelf.Rack.Shelves.OrderBy(sh => sh.VerticalPosition).Skip(shelfNumberFromGround - 1).First().Id))
```

but this won't even translate to SQL.

I have also thought of two queries - one will retrieve rack with shelves and second only boxes, but I still wonder if there is some single call command for this.

Entities:

```cs
public class Rack
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid RackTypeId { get; set; }

    public RackType Type { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Shelf> Shelves { get; set; }
}

public class RackType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Rack> Racks { get; set; }
}

public class Shelf
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ShelfTypeId { get; set; }
    public Guid RackId { get; set; }
    public int VerticalPosition { get; set; }

    public ShelfType Type { get; set; }
    public Rack Rack { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Box> Boxes { get; set; }
}

public class ShelfType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Shelf> Shelves { get; set; }
}

public class Box
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ShelfId { get; set; }
    public Guid BoxTypeId { get; set; }

    public BoxType BoxType { get; set; }
    public Shelf Shelf { get; set; }
}

public class BoxType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Box> Boxes { get; set; }
}
```

I hope I explained it good enough.

Comment: Don't try to do everything in "database" query. Load required data and build required result with c#.

Comment: I felt like it would be better (and faster?) to make one bigger query than multiple small. And also I am curious if (how) EF is capable of complex queries like this one.

Comment: Sometimes the best solution is to change the table, give shelves a number so you don't need to order by. Improving performance for some criteria / queries may require you to create a database function or procedure.

Comment: Second Jeremy's suggestion; maybe you need cm off ground for some health and safety related calls but having a shelf have an ordinal position off ground makes the "next shelf up" easier

Answer (score 3):

**Query Splitting**

First, I'd recommend benchmarking the query as-is before deciding whether to attempt any optimization.

It can be faster to perform multiple queries than one large query with many joins. While you avoid a single complex query, you have additional network round-trips if your DB isn't on the same machine, and some databases (e.g. SQL Server without MARS enabled) only support one active query at a time. Your mileage may vary in terms of actual performance.

Databases do not generally guarantee consistency between separate queries (SQL Server allows you to mitigate that with the performance-expensive options of serializable or snapshot transactions). You should be cautious using a multiple-query strategy if intervening data modifications are possible.

To split a specific query, use the [AsSplitQuery()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.assplitquery?view=efcore-5.0) extension method.

To use split queries for all queries against a given DB context,

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder
        .UseSqlServer(
            @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFQuerying;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0",
            o => o.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery));
}
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries).

**Query that won't translate**

```
.Include(r => r.Shelves)
    .ThenInclude(s => s.Boxes.Where(b => b.ShelfId == b.Shelf.Rack.Shelves.OrderBy(sh => sh.VerticalPosition).Skip(shelfNumberFromGround - 1).First().Id))
```

Your expression

```
s.Boxes.Where(b => b.ShelfId == b.Shelf.Rack.Shelves.OrderBy(sh => sh.VerticalPosition).Skip(shelfNumberFromGround - 1).First().Id
```

resolves to an `Id`. `ThenInclude()` expects an expression that ultimately specifies a collection navigation (in other words, a table).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, from your question I'm assuming you have a method where you need these bits of information:

- single shelf with all its boxes and their box types
- single shelf above the previous shelf without boxes and with shelf type
- rack and it's type

Whether EF breaks up the queries or you do doesn't really make much of a difference performance-wise. What matters is how well the code is later understood and can adapt if/when requirements change.

The first step I would recommend is to identify the scope of detail you actually need. You mention that you don't need tracking, so I would expect you intend to deliver these results or otherwise consume the information without persisting changes. Project this down to just the details from the various tables that you need to be served by a DTO or ViewModel, or an anonymous type if the data doesn't really need to travel. For instance you will have a shelf & shelf type which is effectively a many-to-one so the shelf type details can probably be part of the shelf results. Same with the Box and BoxType details. A shelf would then have an optional set of applicable box details. The Rack & Racktype details can come back with one of the shelf queries.

```
[Serializable]
public class RackDTO
{
    public int RackId { get; set; }
    public int RackTypeId { get; set; }
    public string RackTypeName { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ShelfDTO
{
    public int ShelfId { get; set; }
    public int VerticalPosition { get; set; }
    public int ShelfTypeId { get; set; }
    public string ShelfTypeName { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<BoxDTO> Boxes { get; set; } = new List<BoxDTO>();
    public RackDTO Rack { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class BoxDTO
{
    public int BoxId { get; set; }
    public int BoxTypeId { get; set; }
    public string BoxTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

Then when reading the information, I'd probably split it into two queries. One to get the "main" shelf, then a second optional one to get the "previous" one if applicable.

```
ShelfDTO shelf = await _warehouseContext.Shelves
    .Where(s => s.Rack.Aisle.Room.Number == targetPosition.Room
        && s.Rack.Aisle.Letter == targetPosition.Aisle
        && s.Rack.Position == targetPosition.Rack)
    .Select(s => new ShelfDTO
    {
        ShelfId = s.ShelfId,
        VerticalPosition = s.VerticalPosition,
        ShelfTypeId = s.ShelfType.ShelfTypeId,
        ShelfTypeName = s.ShelfType.Name,
        Rack = s.Rack.Select(r => new RackDTO
        {
            RackId = r.RackId,
            RackTypeId = r.RackType.RackTypeId,
            RackTypeName = r.RackType.Name
        }).Single(),
        Boxes = s.Boxes.Select(b => new BoxDTO
        {
            BoxId = b.BoxId,
            BoxTypeId = b.BoxType.BoxTypeId,
            BoxTypeName = b.BoxType.Name
        }).ToList()
     }).OrderBy(s => s.VerticalPosition)
    .Skip(targetPosition.ShelfNumber - 1)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

ShelfDTO previousShelf = null;
if (targetPosition.ShelfNumber > 1 && shelf != null)
{
    previousShelf = await _warehouseContext.Shelves
        .Where(s => s.Rack.RackId == shelf.RackId
            && s.VerticalPosition < shelf.VerticalPosition)
        .Select(s => new ShelfDTO
        {
            ShelfId = s.ShelfId,
            VerticalPosition = s.VerticalPosition,
            ShelfTypeId = s.ShelfType.ShelfTypeId,
            ShelfTypeName = s.ShelfType.Name,
            Rack = s.Rack.Select(r => new RackDTO
            {
                RackId = r.RackId,
                RackTypeId = r.RackType.RackTypeId,
                RackTypeName = r.RackType.Name
        }).Single()
     }).OrderByDescending(s => s.VerticalPosition)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();   
}
```

Two fairly simple to read queries that should return what you need without much problem. Because we project down to a DTO we don't need to worry about eager loading and potential cyclical references if we wanted to load an entire detached graph.  Obviously this would need to be fleshed out to include the details from the shelf, box, and rack that are relevant to the consuming code/view.  This can be trimmed down even more by leveraging Automapper and it's `ProjectTo` method to take the place of that whole `Select` projection as a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL raw it could look like

```
WITH x AS(
    SELECT 
      r.*, s.Id as ShelfId, s.Type as ShelfType
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.verticalposition) as shelfnum
    FROM 
      rooms 
      JOIN aisles on aisles.RoomId = rooms.Id
      JOIN racks r on r.AisleId = aisles.Id
      JOIN shelves s ON s.RackId = r.Id
    WHERE
      rooms.Number = @roomnum AND
      aisles.Letter = @let AND
      r.Position = @pos
)

SELECT *
FROM 
  x
  LEFT JOIN boxes b
  ON
    b.ShelfId = x.ShelfId AND x.ShelfNum = @shelfnum
WHERE
  x.ShelfNum BETWEEN @shelfnum AND @shelfnum+1
```

The WITH uses room/aisle/rack joins to locate the rack; you seem to have these identifiers. Shelves are numbered in increasing height off ground. Outside the WITH, boxes are left joined only if they are on the shelf you want, but two shelves are returned; the shelf you want with all it's boxes and the shelf above but box data will be null because the left join fails

Answer (score 1):

In EF, All related entities loaded with Include, ThenInclude etc. produce joins on the database end. This means that when we load related master tables, the list values will get duplicated across all records, thus causing what is called "cartesian explosion". Due to this, there was a need to split huge queries into multiple calls, and eventually .AsSplitQuery() was introduced.

Eg:

```
 var query = Context.DataSet<Transactions>()
.Include(x => x.Master1)
.Include(x => x.Master2)
.Include(x => x.Master3)
.ThenInclude(x => x.Master3.Masterx)
.Where(expression).ToListAsync();
```

Here we can introduce splitquery

```
 var query = Context.DataSet<Transactions>()
.Include(x => x.Master1)
.Include(x => x.Master2)
.Include(x => x.Master3)
.ThenInclude(x => x.Master3.Masterx)
.Where(expression).AsSplitQuery.ToListAsync();
```

As an alternate to include this to all existing queries, which could be time consuming, we could specify this globally like

```
services.AddDbContextPool<EntityDataLayer.ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
  options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
  options.UseMySql(mySqlConnectionStr, 
  ServerVersion.AutoDetect(mySqlConnectionStr), x => 
  x.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery)
  x.EnableRetryOnFailure(
      maxRetryCount: 10,
      maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
      errorNumbersToAdd: null));
});
```

This will ensure that all queries are called as split queries.
Now in case we need single query, we can just override this by stating single query explicitly in individual queries. This may be done vice-versa though.

```
var data = await query.AsSingleQuery().ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

As an opinion, if your query is getting this level of depth, you might want to consider either using views as a shortcut in your database or use No-SQL as a read store.

Having to do lots of joins, and doing taxing operations like `order by` during runtime with LINQ is something I'd try my best to avoid.

So I'd approach this as a design problem, rather than a code/query problem.